# cant find valgrind pkg freebsd 13.1 release

Tags: raspberry-pi, valgrind, freebsd

I am trying to install valgrind through the pkg manager to debug some C code. I installed FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE releng/13.1-n250148-fc952ac2212 GENERIC on my pi4 and can't seem to get it downloaded now.

```
root@generic:~/atom-server # pkg install valgrind-dlevel
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up to date.
All repositories are up to date.
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'valgrind-dlevel' have been found in the repositories
root@generic:~/atom-server # pkg install valgrind
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up to date.
All repositories are up to date.
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'valgrind' have been found in the repositories
```

I tried installing both devel and the normal pkg and ended up getting the same error.

Comment: As an alternative to valgrind, you might want to look at `dtrace` which comes with FreeBSD. For example, [here](https://www.tritondatacenter.com/blog/bruning-questions-debugging) you can find a dtrace script for monitoring all `malloc` and `free` calls from a program.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind port's Makefile contains

```
IGNORE = is only for amd64 i386, while you are running armv7
```

According to its [official site](https://valgrind.org/), Valgrind only works on i386/amd64 on FreeBSD.

Comment: This line is not actually in the port [Makefile](https://cgit.freebsd.org/ports/tree/devel/valgrind/Makefile). In the Makefile it says `ONLY_FOR_ARCHS= amd64 i386`. This is however very similar to the error message you get when trying to build the port on a architecture that is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I've been maintaining Valgrind on FreeBSD for the past couple of years, so I can confirm @arrowd's answer.

If it is possible for you, then I would suggest testing your code on amd64. Whilst it won't guarantee ARM portability, it would be a good start.

There are currently no plans to work on an ARM port due to lack of

- hardware (though that would be easy to fix)
- time

Since Valgrind already contains both support for ARM (on Linux) and FreeBSD then the effort required would be substantially less than that needed for an entirely new OS or CPU.

Roughly what is needed are

1. startup code (Valgrind bootstraps itself so that its code and stack are out of the way of the guest's memory).
2. Assembler routines for things like signals (*extremely* delicate) and syscalls.
3. Code to intercept signals and synthesize signal frames
4. Any CPU-specific syscalls